# Finding if two strings are almost similar

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to find out if you strings are almost similar. For example, string like 'Mohan Mehta' should match 'Mohan Mehte' and vice versa. Another example, string like 'Umesh Gupta' should match 'Umash Gupte'.

Basically one string is correct and other one is a mis-spelling of it. All my strings are names of people.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this.

Solution does not have to be 100 percent effective.

Comment: This seems to be a problem of Edit Distance. Least amount of edits means a better match.

Comment: Take a look at the regex module and fuzzy match: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: You could look at the "Levenshtein distance" algorithm.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use [difflib.sequencematcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#sequencematcher-objects) if you want something from the stdlib:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
s_1 = 'Mohan Mehta'
s_2 = 'Mohan Mehte'
print(SequenceMatcher(a=s_1,b=s_2).ratio())
0.909090909091
```

[fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy/0.6.0) is one of numerous libs that you can install, it uses the difflib module with [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/0.12.0). You should also check out the wikipage on [Approximate_string_matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)

Comment: fuzzwuzzy is now: https://github.com/seatgeek/thefuzz

Answer (score 11):

Another approach is to use a "[phonetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm)":

> A phonetic algorithm is an algorithm for indexing of words by their pronunciation.

For example using the [soundex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/soundex/1.1.3) algorithm:

```
>>> import soundex
>>> s = soundex.getInstance()
>>> s.soundex("Umesh Gupta")
'U5213'
>>> s.soundex("Umash Gupte")
'U5213'
>>> s.soundex("Umesh Gupta") == s.soundex("Umash Gupte")
True
```

Comment: rediculous ... it is matching 'camera' and 'canera' .. try it .. how do they sound the same .. can we customize ?

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a [string distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric). There many flavors, but I would recommend starting with the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. To make it an answer, you should indicate which module(s) provides the requisite functions, and include a code example.

Comment: This is an answer to the question as presented,

Comment: While this is technically an answer, it's not ideal because the actual answer data is off-site. Please consider adding the details from your sources into your answer.

Answer (score 3):

you might want to look at [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/index.html) (The Natural Language Toolkit), specifically the [nltk.metrics](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html#module-nltk.metrics.distance) package, which implements various string distance algorithms, including the Levenshtein distance mentioned already.

Answer (score 1):

You could split the string and check to see if it contains at least one first/last name that is correct.

Answer (score -2):

```
// calculate the similarity between 2 strings

  public static double similarity(String s1, String s2) {
    String longer = s1, shorter = s2;
    if (s1.length() < s2.length()) { // longer should always have greater length
      longer = s2; shorter = s1;
    }
    int longerLength = longer.length();
    if (longerLength == 0) { return 1.0; /* both strings are zero length */ }
    /* // If you have StringUtils, you can use it to calculate the edit distance:
    return (longerLength - StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(longer, shorter)) /
                               (double) longerLength; */
    return (longerLength - editDistance(longer, shorter)) / (double) longerLength;

  }

  // Example implementation of the Levenshtein Edit Distance
  // See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Java
  public static int editDistance(String s1, String s2) {
    s1 = s1.toLowerCase();
    s2 = s2.toLowerCase();

    int[] costs = new int[s2.length() + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= s1.length(); i++) {
      int lastValue = i;
      for (int j = 0; j <= s2.length(); j++) {
        if (i == 0)
          costs[j] = j;
        else {
          if (j > 0) {
            int newValue = costs[j - 1];
            if (s1.charAt(i - 1) != s2.charAt(j - 1))
              newValue = Math.min(Math.min(newValue, lastValue),
                  costs[j]) + 1;
            costs[j - 1] = lastValue;
            lastValue = newValue;
          }
        }
      }
      if (i > 0)
        costs[s2.length()] = lastValue;
    }
    return costs[s2.length()];
  }
```