# Determining how much two strings match

Tags: python, string, match

Let's say we have 3 strings

```
songA = "(Used to Be A) Cha-Cha.flac"
songB = "(Used to Be A) Cha-Cha [Alt Take].flac"
```

And we want to match a third string

```
songC = "(Used to Be A) Cha-Cha.flac"
```

Now, although both songA and SongB match songC it is clear that songA is a 'better' match since it doesn't have the [Alt Take] part, thus making a perfect match. If I use the `songA in songB` method both will be matched, so how can I account for how good a match is?

Comment: calculate the [hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). perfect matches have a hamming distance of `0`.

Comment: @MarcB hamming distance not the best metric here, he needs ability to remove arbitrary pieces of the string to match songB to songC.

Comment: Note that in your example, `songC in songB` is `False`

Comment: Levenshtein distance is probably what you're looking for.,,,

Comment: Actually @gt6989b I believe you might have misunderstood a little, I just need to know 'how much' one is a match of the other.

Comment: @gt6989b, my bad I forgot the .flac, the code is removing them beforehand.

Comment: just found this: http://chairnerd.seatgeek.com/fuzzywuzzy-fuzzy-string-matching-in-python/ .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642940/finding-if-two-strings-are-almost-similar

Comment: Ended up using [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fuzzywuzzy/0.6.0). Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-Levenshtein/) lib to compute the levenshtein distance between the two strings:

```
import Levenshtein
Levenshtein.distance(songC, songA) # 0
Levenshtein.distance(songC, songB) # 11
```