# Merge rows based on 2 field match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge a specific column if the rows are similar, for example here "l.instagram.com" and "instagram.com" is actually the same source so I would like to merge activeUsers into instagram.com.

Give:

```
     sessionSource dateRange  activeUsers  
0     snapchat.com  previous            1
1     snapchat.com   current            1
2  l.instagram.com  previous           71
3  l.instagram.com   current           23
4    instagram.com  previous            5
5    instagram.com   current            0
```

Each sessionSource has a row for "current" and "previous" period. But I want to merge l.instagram.com into instagram.com activeUsers since they are from the same source.

The desired result would look like this:

```
     sessionSource dateRange  activeUsers  
0     snapchat.com  previous            1
1     snapchat.com   current            1
4    instagram.com  previous           76
5    instagram.com   current           23
```

I have tried few answers but I couldn't get to that result.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: my intuition tells me this is a tough problem to generalize. if you knew ahead of time the unique website strings in sessionSource you wanted to end up with, then it's not too difficult of a problem because you can match all of the current strings to the desired strings. but if you don't know what strings you want to end up with, you need to determine which groups of strings are similar to each other – most likely using a string similarity library like fuzzywuzzy. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078596/grouping-by-almost-similar-strings) is pretty similar to yours

Comment: you're right, this would be a tough one if similarity was not clearly defined. In my case I know that only 1 string is causing issue so the solution I need doesn't have to be scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the value l.instagram.com'with instagram.com: `df['sessionSource']=df['sessionSource'].replace('l.instagram.com','instagram.com')`

And then group by the columns 'sessionSource' & 'dataRange' and sum 'activeUsers':

```
sum_df = df.groupby(['sessionSource','dataRange']).agg({'activeUsers': 'sum'})


sum_df=sum_df.reset_index()
sum_df
```

This sum_df will give what you want. Hope this helps.

(image attached of the solution and output)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Worked as expected, thank you so much Mostafa.

Comment: Most welcome.. please give a up to it :)